# Integrate Wowza Module and Play Framework For Restful API Development

Tags: rest, playframework, restful-architecture, wowza

I am going to write a restful api with wowza

Currently i am using Wowza default HTTP Provider Class for that
but Wowza HTTP Provider is not that much scalable.

I need to know can i somehow integrate my wowza modules with  play framework or with some other framework for api development?

Thanks